# Mockito Matchers List<Object>

Tags: list, mockito, matcher

I need to create a mockito that test if he gets a list of Object in entrance.

But I find only Matchers.anyList. I need to specify a List.

Can anyone help plz ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test with specific values of a list of object :

Matchers.eq(T value)

and you should generate equals and hashCode() in the Object

Comment: In Mockito 2 Matchers is deprecated, org.mockito.Mockito.eq can be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Replace MyObject with your Object

```
Matchers.<List<MyObject>>any()
```